# How can I debug my application while USB tethering is enabled?

Tags: usb-debugging, usb-tethering

I want to debug my application on the phone and at the same time I want to enable USB tethering so that I can access Internet on my PC.

Is there any way so that I can connect my phone then enable USB Tethering and USB Debugging at the same time? Are there any applications exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you have root, once USB tethering is enabled, go to your terminal on Android and run

```
su (or su root)
adbd start (or sudo adbd start without previous su line)
```

That will start the daemon while your USB is in Ethernet mode and allow you to connect from your PC.

Comment: Basically, gain root access and start the adb daemon manually.